# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' mxnet

Tags: python-2.7, mxnet

I have been trying to learn mxnet from the tutorial while doing data loading stuff I am getting 'int' doesn't have '**getitem**' but i am not able to find the location of error please help me thanks:

```
import mxnet as mx
import numpy as np

class SimpleData :
    def __init__(self,data,label,pad = 0):
        self.data = data
        self.label = label
        self.pad = pad

class SimpleIter:
        def __init__(self,mean,std,data_shape,label_shape,num_of_classes,num_batch = 10):
        self._provide_data = zip(['data'],data_shape[0])
        self._provide_label = zip(['softmax_label'],label_shape[0])
        self.cur_batch = 0
        self.num_batch = 10
        self.mean = mean 
        self.std = std
        self.data_shape = data_shape[0]
        self.label_shape = label_shape[0]
        self.num_of_classes  = num_of_classes

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def reset(self):
        self.cur_batch = 0

    @property 
    def provide_data(self):
        return self._provide_data

    @property
    def provide_label(self):
        return self._provide_label

    def next(self):
        if(self.cur_batch < self.num_batch):
            self.cur_batch += 1
            data = [mx.nd.array(np.random.normal(self.mean,self.std,    ((self.data_shape)[0][0]/self.num_batch,self.data_shape[0][1])))]
            label = [mx.nd.array(np.random.randint(0,10,    ((self.data_shape)[0][1]/self.num_batch)))]
            print data
            print label
            return SimpleBatch(data,label)
        else:
            raise StopIteration

class SyntheticData:
    def     __init__(self,mean,std,num_records,num_of_features,num_classes):
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std
        self.data_shape = zip(num_records,num_of_features)
        self.label_shape = zip(num_records,)
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        def get_iter(self):
            return     SimpleIter(self.mean,self.std,self.data_shape,self.label_shape,self.num_classes)
net = mx.sym.Variable('data')
net = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data = net,name = 'fc1',num_hidden = 64)
net = mx.sym.Activation(data = net,name = 'relu_1',act_type = 'relu')
net = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data = net,name = 'fc2',num_hidden = 10)
net = mx.sym.SoftmaxOutput(data = net,name = 'softmax')
data = SyntheticData(10,128,[100],[100],10) 
mod.fit(data.get_iter(), 
    eval_data=data.get_iter(),
    optimizer='sgd',
    optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.1},
    eval_metric='acc',
    num_epoch = 5)
```

the error is:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-273-a7375f022406> in <module>()
      4         optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.1},
      5         eval_metric='acc',
----> 6         num_epoch = 5)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/base_module.pyc in fit(self, train_data, eval_data, eval_metric, epoch_end_callback, batch_end_callback, kvstore, optimizer, optimizer_params, eval_end_callback, eval_batch_end_callback, initializer, arg_params, aux_params, allow_missing, force_rebind, force_init, begin_epoch, num_epoch, validation_metric, monitor)
    440 
    441         self.bind(data_shapes=train_data.provide_data, label_shapes=train_data.provide_label,
--> 442                   for_training=True, force_rebind=force_rebind)
    443         if monitor is not None:
    444             self.install_monitor(monitor)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/module.pyc in bind(self, data_shapes, label_shapes, for_training, inputs_need_grad, force_rebind, shared_module, grad_req)
    386                                                      fixed_param_names=self._fixed_param_names,
    387                                                      grad_req=grad_req,
--> 388                                                      state_names=self._state_names)
    389         self._total_exec_bytes = self._exec_group._total_exec_bytes
    390         if shared_module is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.pyc in __init__(self, symbol, contexts, workload, data_shapes, label_shapes, param_names, for_training, inputs_need_grad, shared_group, logger, fixed_param_names, grad_req, state_names)
    203                                for name in self.symbol.list_outputs()]
    204 
--> 205         self.bind_exec(data_shapes, label_shapes, shared_group)
    206 
    207     def decide_slices(self, data_shapes):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.pyc in bind_exec(self, data_shapes, label_shapes, shared_group, reshape)
    282 
    283         # calculate workload and bind executors
--> 284         self.data_layouts = self.decide_slices(data_shapes)
    285         if label_shapes is not None:
    286             # call it to make sure labels has the same batch size     as data

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.4-    py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.pyc in decide_slices(self,     data_shapes)
       220                 continue
       221 
-->     222             batch_size = shape[axis]
       223             if self.batch_size is not None:
       224                 assert batch_size == self.batch_size, ("all data      must have the same batch size: "

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: You don't appear to be showing the code that actually generated the error (the top section of the traceback). Somewhere it looks like you're calling a `fit()` method, and it looks like the first parameter (`train_data`) is not what it's expecting.

Comment: oh sorry thanks for noticing it,now I have added the complete code

Comment: What is 'mod'? Also, the arguments for fit function looks incorrect. Can you pick an example from mxnet github and modify it to fit your need? Here is an example of data iterator, if that is what you are looking for: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/recommenders/movielens_data.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the definition of your `data_shape`.

`self.data_shape = data_shape[0]`

As you defined it, `self.data_shape` is just an int. In your case, I think it should be just:

`self.data_shape = data_shape`

So that when `shape[axis]` is accessed from `decide_slices` it can get the number of elements.